# Extract file name from list

Tags: java, list, file, for-loop, filelist

During loop my list contains csv files, I want to get file name, under which I will save my output.

**Example**:

File list: `t1.csv`, `t2.csv`, `t3.csv`

Output list should look: `t1.xml, t2.xml, t3.xml`

**sample.java**

```
List<String> csvFiles = new ArrayList<String>();                            
try {
    File[] files = new File(textCSV.getText()).listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            csvFiles.add(file.getName());
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<csvFiles.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(csvFiles.get(i));                        
        String Output = ".xml" //how to put here csv name
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(csvFiles.get(i).replace(".csv", ".xml"));`

Comment: thx, it's working as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite like this.

```
List<String> csvFiles = new ArrayList<String>();                            
    try {
        File[] files = new File(textCSV.getText()).listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                csvFiles.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<csvFiles.size();i++)
        {
           System.out.println(csvFiles.get(i));             

           String Output = csvFiles.get(i).substring(0, csvFiles.get(i).indexOf(".")) + ".xml" //how to put here csv name
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe you should replace your `indexOf` with `lastIndexOf` in case the file contains more than one "." (dot) in the filename :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways that I can think of where you can extract only the filename.

1. **Using Apache Commons Library**

   ```
   FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getName());
   ```
2. In case your files will always **contain at least one extension** (at least one "." in the file name)

   ```
   file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().lastIndexOf("."));
   ```
3. In case there are files which don't contain any extension

   ```
   int index = file.getName().lastIndexOf(".");
   if (index == -1) {
       file.getName();
   } else {
       file.getName().substring(0, index);
   }
   ```

You can replace your `csvFiles.add(file.getName());` to `csvFiles.add();` with argument as any of the above lines.